# SAS Data Integration Studio: How to convert a char date column to num date column

Tags: date, char, sas, numeric

i have a table with a column which is a char type. The values are all in the format IS8601DT format '2014-02-18T16:02:00.000'. Is there a function or other simple way to convert this in any num date format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`anydtdtm32.`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002605552.htm) informat with `input` function as shown below:

```
data test;
mydate_char='2014-02-18T16:02:00.000';
mydate_num=input(mydate_char, anydtdtm32.);
format mydate_num datetime22.;
run;
/*mydate_num:18FEB2014:16:02:00*/
```